# setting lower half of a register in thumb2

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I am using the due board, which is cortex-m3, using thumb2. I need to use a bunch of IO ports, these all have addresses that start with 0x400E, like 0x400E0E3C etc. I am using a register to store these addresses. As I do this a bunch of times, I load the top half of the register with the address 400E. How do I load the bottom half of the address with the immediate 16 bit value without disturbing the upper half.

this works -

```
movw r8, #400E
movt r8, 0E3C
```

I want to do the second instructiuon only once, but the issue is that every time i call movw, it resets the upper half of the register to 0. I need a single instruction that will load the bottom half of a register without disturbing the top half.

Comment: There is no single ARM instruction to load the low 16 bits without affecting the top 16.  You can rotate 16, move to the top half, and rotate 16 again, but this is no better than using 2 16-bit immediate moves. A different solution is to put the port addresses in a table, load a register with the table address, and load with register+offset addresses.

Comment: movw+movt+ldr will probably be faster than ldr+ldr.

Comment: just thought of a better and simple way, i can populate the 0x400E0000 in the register and use the lower half as and offset and just load the memory location. P.S - that didnt work, i get offset out of range.

Comment: You could use `BFI`, but you'd need a spare intermediate register to load the immediates into before inserting them, and it's still two instructions per load so you might as well just use `MOVT`.

Comment: yeah the offset stuff worked because the first 5  hex digits of my addresses are same, leaving a 12 bit address, which fits.

Answer (score 0):

If the registers are close, then use an index. Ie, `str rn, [rB, #offset]`. The *offset* is quite [generous +12bits](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204f/Bcfihdhj.html).

The load/store address modes are meant to efficiently handle structures. You can treat a register bank like a structure. `rB` is the base index of your register bank; maybe *0x400e0e00*.

If the range is so large, you may need to mask a few bits (see `bic` and `orr`) in the base `rB`.  Ie, if you have *rB = 0x400e0000* (access to 0x400e0fff) and you need *0x400ef010*, then,

```
orr rB, rB, #0xf000 # select high portion
ldr rn, [rB, #10]   # offset in high portion.
bic rB, rB, #0xf000 # back to low portion.
```

`bfc` and `bfi` can also be useful, but you might just keep multiple `rB` registers, if your algorithm permits.